# Group by on datatable by using linq query

Tags: linq, datatable

Following are rows in my datatable:

```
TemplateName    Task                        Days
PT_Case     Assign Acceptance Task          83
PT_Case     Assign Acceptance Task          64
PT_Case     Assign Metadata Task            65
PT_Case     Assign Metadata Task            93  
PT_Type     Complete Metadata Task          67
PT_Type     Complete Metadata Task          -3
PT_Type     Assign Acceptance Task          67
PT_Type     Assign Acceptance Task          61
```

I need following output by linq query:

```
TemplateName         Task              Days  TotalDays
PT_Case    Assign Acceptance Task      73    152
PT_Case      Assign Metadata Task      79    152
PT_Type    Complete Metadata Task      32    96
PT_Type    Assign Acceptance Task      64    96
```

Note: "Days" calculated as average of task days. 
Please suggest, how to achieve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would start with `AsEnumerable()` call. What is `Days`? What is `TotalDays`? Where is your code? It's completely not clear how you get those numbers, and what your problem is

Comment: I Have above rows in datatable, now I have to group by it by "TemplatgeName" and "Task" because I have to get sum of task days.
As well as I have to sum days agains TemplateName and that is my TotalDays column in result query.

Comment: How do you get numbers for `Days`? Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
            group r by r.Field<string>("TemplateName") into templates
            let totalDays = templates.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Days"))
            from t in templates
            group t by new
            {
                TemplateName = templates.Key,
                Task = t.Field<string>("Task"),
                TotalDays = totalDays
            } into tasks
            select new
            {
                tasks.Key.TemplateName,
                tasks.Key.Task,
                Days = tasks.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Days")),
                tasks.Key.TotalDays
            };
```

It groups rows by template name and calculates total days for template. Then it groups template rows by task, and calculates days for tasks. Thats how I understand what you want to do. But result differs from your expected result (I don't understand how you get those values):

```
 TemplateName         Task              Days  TotalDays
    PT_Case    Assign Acceptance Task   147   305
    PT_Case      Assign Metadata Task   158   305
    PT_Type    Complete Metadata Task    64   192
    PT_Type    Assign Acceptance Task   128   192
```

Comment: Really thanks for your reply, but now how can i convert "query" to datatable? I know, my questions are looking silly but I am new in these.

Comment: You can use code from [How to: Implement CopyToDataTable<T> Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx) article. Also consider if you really need this data as DataTable? Why not keep list of objects?

Comment: I have to convert result into XML.

Comment: You can use XML Serialization. Sorry, need to go now

Comment: Hi, I have checked above query. But Its not returning any result.

Comment: @PrashantKhadatkar sorry, but I verified it and copy-pasted results which you can see in answer. Make sure your code does not differ from mine

Comment: Hi, Now I need little modification in result. I need "Days" should be a average days as per group by we did. So, I have modified your query as "tasks.Sum(r => int.Parse(r.Field<string>("AvgDays")))/ tasks.Count()" But now, how can I get TotalsDays of this?

Comment: @PrashantKhadatkar there is `Average` method in Linq. You can use `tasks.Average(r => r.Field<int>("Days"))`

Comment: Ok, but now how can I get totalDays column values as per average now?

Comment: @PrashantKhadatkar total days should stay same, if I'm not missing something